# Tabbar Background image is not perfectly placing

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios9, uitabbar

I have a `UITabBarController` i want to change its background image when i change the background image to using this code

`self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imagenamed:@"texture.jpg"]];`

Instead of changing the `tabBar` background image it changes the whole screens background image.

[image: Change Image of Red Rectangular Box Below]
[image: Image2 Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set bg image:

```
UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomUITabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

Comment: No.. You aren't getting my point. Please view both of the pictures i want textured background image as my tabBar background. But when i assign it it changes the background image of the entire TabBarController as shown in below picture. i want to change the background image of Tabbar only the redded area in the above picture.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `AppDelegate` after setting `tabBarController` as `rootViewController`

```
UITabBarItem *item = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
item.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourDeselectImage.png"];
item.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourSelectImage.png"];
```